# Error swtching to another view Ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

Hi I am just new to AngularJS. I want to make my app route from cart view to checkout view when a checkout button is clicked. However I'm really struggling on how to make this supposed to be a simple task.. This is what I have so far. I'll cut some other codes.

```
  $stateProvider.state("app", {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.cart', {
    url: "/cart",
    views: {
      'tab-cart': {
        templateUrl: "templates/cart.html",
        controller: 'CartCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state("app.checkout", {
    url: "/checkout",
    views: {
      'tab-checkout': {
        templateUrl: "templates/checkout.html",
        controller: "CheckoutCtrl"
      }
    }
  })
```

And this is the button in my `cart.html`

```
<a class="button button-block button-positive button-checkout" 
    href="#/tab/checkout">
    Checkout
</a>
```

I'm just confused that it is working on tabs.

```
  <ion-tab title="Cart" icon-off="ion-ios-cart" icon-on="ion-ios-cart" href="#/tab/cart">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-cart"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
```

I've searched and tried some other solutions but it's not working for me. I've tried:

```
href="#/app/checkout"

ui-sref="app.checkout"

$location.path("#/app/checkout"); //from the controller
```

Answer (score 0):

From your CartCtrl controller, add this funciont to change the view (make sure to  inject  $state into your controller):

```
$scope.goToCheckOut = function(){
     $state.go('app.checkout');
}
```

Then, change the button behavior in cart.html:

`<a class="button button-block button-positive button-checkout" 
       ng-click="goToCheckOut()">
        Checkout
    </a>`